# How can I run an EF Core `update database` task, with the startup project specified, in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ef-core-2.0

If I run the following command in my command line: 
`dotnet ef database update --startup-project /code/spike/MyProj.Web`

The command runs fine.

If I set up a task in `tasks.json` like this:

```
{
      "label": "update database",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "ef",
        "database",
        "update",
        "--startup-project ${workspaceFolder}/MyProj.Web"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
    }
```

I get the following error:

`Startup project 'MyProj.Data.csproj' targets framework '.NETStandard'. There is no runtime associated with this framework, and projects targeting it cannot be executed directly. To use the Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools with this project, add an executable project targeting .NET Core or .NET Framework that references this project, and set it as the startup project using --startup-project; or, update this project to cross-target .NET Core or .NET Framework. For more information on using the EF Core Tools with .NET Standard projects, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2034781`

Is there a way to use `--startup-project` for EF Core in a VS Code task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your running from the command line in the MyProj.Data project folder?

VS Code will run the task at the workspace folder level, so you need to add the --project arg pointing to the MyProj.Data.csproj file.

Also, VS Code adds quotes around the args if they contain spaces, so you need to add the arg and value seperately.

e.g.:

```
{
    "label": "update database",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "type": "process",
    "args": [
        "ef",
        "database",
        "update",
        "--project", "${workspaceFolder}/MyProj.Data/MyProj.Data.csproj",
        "--startup-project", "${workspaceFolder}/MyProj.Web"
    ],
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Comment: I set the cwd in the options, but had left it out of the example. Ultimately it was splitting "--startup-project" and "${WorkspaceFolder}/MyProj.Web" into separate args. Thank you!